# Android - Creating Custom Compound Component

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view, custom-component, custom-view

I have started coding in Android just a couple of weeks ago and before that i never used oop (i have some background in c and embeded c for microcontrollers etc), so because of that i might get this idea totally wrong, but i need help to continue:

I have created a sample activity to use as an UI which worked perfectly for my intentions. After that i wanted to use this as a custom compound for future designs so i tried to make changes but couldnt figure that out. The compound has 3 textviews and 2 buttons. i have also implemented gestures to use beside the buttons (so i can scroll up or down to change values).

Now when i use this custom compound, i get an error. I couldn't figure why.

here my compound layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/CustomTouchPickerLayout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".CustomTouchPickerActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewMid"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewTop"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:onClick="onClickMid"
    android:paddingBottom="20sp"
    android:paddingTop="20sp"
    android:textSize="45sp" 
    android:text="Mid"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewBot"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewMid"
    android:textSize="22sp" 
    android:text="Bot"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewTop"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewBot"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
    android:textSize="22sp" 
    android:text="Top"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonTop"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="OnClickButtonTop"
    android:text="Up" 
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonBot"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewBot"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="OnClickButtonBot"
    android:text="Down" />
```

This is my .java file for the compound:

```
package com.vestel.customtouchpicker;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomTouchPicker extends RelativeLayout {

public int count_sag=0;
public int count_sol=0;
public int count_button_sol=0;
public int count_button_sag=0;
private GestureDetector gestureDetector;




public CustomTouchPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context,attrs);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_custom_touch_picker,this);

    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new SwipeGestureDetector());

    TextView textViewTop = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewTop);
    TextView textViewBot = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewBot);
    TextView textViewMid = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewMid);

    Button buttonTop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonTop);
    Button buttonBot = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBot);

    textViewTop.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    textViewBot.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    buttonTop.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);
    buttonBot.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);

    textViewTop.setText("2°");
    textViewMid.setText("4°");
    textViewBot.setText("6°");

}
private class SwipeGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    // Swipe properties, you can change it to make the swipe
    // longer or shorter and speed
    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
    private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 200;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        try {
            float diffAbs = Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY());
            float diff = e1.getX() - e2.getX();
            float diff_y = e1.getY() - e2.getY();
            float diffAbs_x = Math.abs(e1.getX() - e2.getY());

            TextView textViewTop = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewTop);
            // down swipe
            if(textViewTop.getVisibility()==0){
                if (e1.getY()>e2.getY()) {
                    if(diff_y>20)
                    {
                        count_button_sol=count_button_sol+1;
                    }
                    CustomTouchPicker.this.onDownSwipe();



                }
                // up swipe
                else if (e1.getY()<e2.getY()) 
                {
                    if(-diff_y>20){
                        count_button_sol=count_button_sol+1;
                    }
                    CustomTouchPicker.this.onUpSwipe();
                }
            } 
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("YourActivity", "Error on gestures");
        }
        return false;
    }   
}
public void onClickMid(View view) 
{
    count_sol=count_sol+1;
    if(count_sol%2==1){
        TextView textViewTop = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewTop);
        TextView textViewBot = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewBot);            

        Button buttonTop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonTop);
        Button buttonBot = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBot);           

        textViewTop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        textViewBot.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        buttonTop.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
        buttonBot.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);

        textViewBot.setAlpha(0.2f);
        textViewTop.setAlpha(0.2f);
    }
    else
    {
        TextView textViewTop = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewTop);
        TextView textViewBot = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewBot);

        Button buttonTop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonTop);
        Button buttonBot = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBot);

        textViewTop.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        textViewBot.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        buttonTop.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);
        buttonBot.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
public void OnClickButtonTop (View view){

    TextView textViewTop = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewTop);        
    TextView textViewBot = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewBot);
    TextView textViewMid = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewMid);

    switch (count_button_sol%4)
    {       
    case 0: textViewTop.setText("2°");
    textViewMid.setText("4°");
    textViewBot.setText("6°");
    break;
    case 1: textViewTop.setText("4°");
    textViewMid.setText("6°");
    textViewBot.setText("8°");
    break;
    case 2: textViewTop.setText("6°");
    textViewMid.setText("8°");
    textViewBot.setText("2°");
    break;
    case 3: textViewTop.setText("8°");
    textViewMid.setText("2°");
    textViewBot.setText("4°");
    break;
    default:textViewTop.setText("2°");
    textViewMid.setText("4°");
    textViewBot.setText("6°");
    break;
    }
    count_button_sol=count_button_sol+1;
}
public void OnClickButtonBot (View view){

    TextView textViewTop = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewTop);        
    TextView textViewBot = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewBot);
    TextView textViewMid = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewMid);

    switch (count_button_sol%4)
    {

    case 3: textViewTop.setText("2°");
    textViewMid.setText("4°");
    textViewBot.setText("6°");
    break;
    case 2: textViewTop.setText("4°");
    textViewMid.setText("6°");
    textViewBot.setText("8°");
    break;
    case 1: textViewTop.setText("6°");
    textViewMid.setText("8°");
    textViewBot.setText("2°");
    break;
    case 0: textViewTop.setText("8°");
    textViewMid.setText("2°");
    textViewBot.setText("4°");
    break;
    default:textViewTop.setText("2°");
    textViewMid.setText("4°");
    textViewBot.setText("6°");
    break;
    }
    count_button_sol=count_button_sol+1;
}
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) 
    {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}


private void onDownSwipe() 
{
    TextView textViewTop = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewTop);
    TextView textViewBot = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewBot);
    TextView textViewMid = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewMid);

    switch (count_button_sol%4){
    case 0: textViewTop.setText("2°");
    textViewMid.setText("4°");
    textViewBot.setText("6°");
    break;
    case 1: textViewTop.setText("4°");
    textViewMid.setText("6°");
    textViewBot.setText("8°");
    break;
    case 2: textViewTop.setText("6°");
    textViewMid.setText("8°");
    textViewBot.setText("2°");
    break;
    case 3: textViewTop.setText("8°");
    textViewMid.setText("2°");
    textViewBot.setText("4°");
    break;
    default:textViewTop.setText("2°");
    textViewMid.setText("4°");
    textViewBot.setText("6°");
    break;
    }
}       
private void onUpSwipe() {
    TextView textViewTop = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewTop);
    //          textViewTop.setAlpha(0.5f);
    TextView textViewBot = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewBot);
    TextView textViewMid = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewMid);
    //          textViewBot.setAlpha(0.5f);
    switch (count_button_sol%4){
    case 3: textViewTop.setText("2°");
    textViewMid.setText("4°");
    textViewBot.setText("6°");
    break;
    case 2: textViewTop.setText("4°");
    textViewMid.setText("6°");
    textViewBot.setText("8°");
    break;
    case 1: textViewTop.setText("6°");
    textViewMid.setText("8°");
    textViewBot.setText("2°");
    break;
    case 0: textViewTop.setText("8°");
    textViewMid.setText("2°");
    textViewBot.setText("4°");
    break;
    default:textViewTop.setText("2°");
    textViewMid.setText("4°");
    textViewBot.setText("6°");
    break;

    }
}

}
```

This is my main activity layout for test

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<com.vestel.customtouchpicker
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here the MainActivity.java

```
package com.vestel.customtouchpicker;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}



}
```

and android manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.vestel.customtouchpicker"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.vestel.customtouchpicker.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

and lastly my logcat

```
    04-04 14:41:59.049: E/Trace(31339): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-04 14:41:59.319: E/AndroidRuntime(31339): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-04 14:41:59.319: E/AndroidRuntime(31339): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vestel.customtouchpicker/com.vestel.customtouchpicker.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class com.vestel.customtouchpicker
04-04 14:41:59.319: E/AndroidRuntime(31339):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2351)
04-04 14:41:59.319: E/AndroidRuntime(31339):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
04-04 14:41:59.319: E/AndroidRuntime(31339):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
04-04 14:41:59.319: E/AndroidRuntime(31339):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331)
04-04 14:41:59.319: E/AndroidRuntime(31339):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-04 14:41:59.319: E/AndroidRuntime(31339):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
04-04 14:41:59.319: E/AndroidRuntime(31339):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5454)
04-04 14:41:59.319: E/AndroidRuntime(31339):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-04 14:41:59.319: E/AndroidRuntime(31339):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-04 14:41:59.319: E/AndroidRuntime(31339):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
04-04 14:41:59.319: E/AndroidRuntime(31339):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
04-04 14:41:59.319: E/AndroidRuntime(31339):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-04 14:41:59.319: E/AndroidRuntime(31339): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class com.vestel.customtouchpicker
04-04 14:41:59.319: E/AndroidRuntime(31339):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
04-04 14:41:59.319: E/AndroidRuntime(31339):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
04-04 14:41:59.319: E/AndroidRuntime(31339):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
04-04 14:41:59.319: E/AndroidRuntime(31339):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
04-04 14:41:59.319: E/AndroidRuntime(31339):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
04-04 14:41:59.319: E/AndroidRuntime(31339):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:363)
04-04 14:41:59.319: E/AndroidRuntime(31339):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1912)
04-04 14:41:59.319: E/AndroidRuntime(31339):    at com.vestel.customtouchpicker.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
04-04 14:41:59.319: E/AndroidRuntime(31339):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5066)
04-04 14:41:59.319: E/AndroidRuntime(31339):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1101)
04-04 14:41:59.319: E/AndroidRuntime(31339):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
04-04 14:41:59.319: E/AndroidRuntime(31339):    ... 11 more
04-04 14:41:59.319: E/AndroidRuntime(31339): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.vestel.customtouchpicker
04-04 14:41:59.319: E/AndroidRuntime(31339):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
04-04 14:41:59.319: E/AndroidRuntime(31339):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
04-04 14:41:59.319: E/AndroidRuntime(31339):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
04-04 14:41:59.319: E/AndroidRuntime(31339):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
04-04 14:41:59.319: E/AndroidRuntime(31339):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
04-04 14:41:59.319: E/AndroidRuntime(31339):    ... 21 more
```

by the way if you use the codes as activity directly it works (of course i removed some lines like the "setContentView" and etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing your class name in main activity layout. It was unable to find class `com.vestel.customtouchpicker`, this is just package name of your custom component not class name. Give fully qualified name as `com.vestel.customtouchpicker.CustomTouchPicker` in your main activity layout, it should work.

Change to:

```
<com.vestel.customtouchpicker.CustomTouchPicker
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

EDIT: This is answer for ClassNotFoundException, i didn't inspect all of your code. So there may be another issue.

Comment: Thank you! You made my day :D

i got another answer though, the hint you gave is worked but, now applications is looking for the "onClick" handler in the main activity is it possible to reroute it to use its own callback function? (as i wrote in the question, i handle the onclicks in the customtouchpicker.java not in the MainActivity.java)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this error is caused in the below two lines:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_custom_touch_picker,this);
```

Because, "context" in context.getSystemService might be throwing the exception.
May be you can use

```
context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService
```

since you are attempting to use the context outside of the activity